# Why it's not correct? Regex in dictionary, value not found even though should be inside

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, assert

I have a code for an exercise of regexes and a dictionary. I have to create a list of dictiionaries. I did and it's correct, however, when testing one item that should be inside the dictionary, the assignment says that it's not when everything I see it's correct. The time value of that item seems that it's not on the dictionary when it is. I will show my code and then the code that asses it and the messaage of error.

```
import re

def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    logdatalines = logdata.splitlines()
    logs = []
    for line in logdatalines:
        dictionary = to_dictionary(line)
        logs.append(dictionary)
    return logs


def to_dictionary(line):
    dictionary = {}
    dictionary["host"] = re.findall("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", line)
    dictionary["user_name"] = re.findall("-* -+ [a-z]*[0-9]*", line)
    dictionary["time"] = re.findall("[0-9]+\/[A-Z][a-z]*\/[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+ -[0-9]+", line)
    dictionary["request"] = re.findall("[A-Z]+ .*", line)
    return dictionary
```

And then we have this assert code to test the code:

```
assert len(logs()) == 979

one_item={'host': '146.204.224.152',
  'user_name': 'feest6811',
  'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
  'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
assert one_item in logs(), "Sorry, this item should be in the log results, check your formating"
```

The text file is something like this but with more data (each line ends after the GET(or other)/...":

```None
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100 22921
2.179.103.97 - lind8584 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:36 -0700] "POST /grow/front-end/e-commerce/robust HTTP/2.0" 304 14641
241.114.184.133 - tromp8355 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:37 -0700] "GET /redefine/orchestrate HTTP/1.0" 204 29059
224.188.38.4 - keebler1423 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:40 -0700] "PUT /orchestrate/out-of-the-box/unleash/syndicate HTTP/1.1" 404 28211
94.11.36.112 - klein8508 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:41 -0700] "POST /enhance/solutions/bricks-and-clicks HTTP/1.1" 404 24768
126.196.238.197 - gusikowski9864 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:45 -0700] "DELETE /rich/reinvent HTTP/2.0" 405 7894
103.247.168.212 - medhurst2732 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:49 -0700] "HEAD /scale/global/leverage HTTP/1.0" 203 15844
57.86.153.68 - dubuque8645 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:50 -0700] "POST /innovative/roi/robust/systems HTTP/1.1" 406 29046
231.220.8.214 - luettgen1860 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:52 -0700] "HEAD /systems/sexy HTTP/1.1" 201 2578
```

Comment: As an aside, it is wasteful to call `logs()` multiple times. You should do `dict_list = logs()` and do your assertions against `dict_list`.

Comment: Are you saying that the second assertion is failing? You also say that your list of dictionaries is "correct" but "The time value of that item seems that it's not on the dictionary when it is." This second sentence makes no sense to me but surely contradicts your first statement about the list being correct. We also don't know what the input data is nor the rules for matching, so in case one or more of your regular expressions is incorrect, we can offer no help with that.

Comment: I edited so you can see now how would be the text (it's very big but each line is similar)

Comment: I'm saying that is correct because when i run the program on pycharm it prints the results that i want on each line. The time ends at-0700 like shoud be.

Comment: Then what exactly is your error? You did not answer my previous question: is an assertion failing and if so, which one, or is it some other problem. I am still trying to understand  what you are trying to say with "The time value of that item seems that it's not on the dictionary when it is.".

Comment: Oh sorry, well, the second assertion is failing as it's searching for a dictionary inside the dictionary list and it's not finding the time value

Comment: The length is correct so the list of dictionaries has all the dictionaries that should have (979)

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `re.findall()` which returns a list of matched items. Assuming there is only one match per line it would return:

```Python
['21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700']
```

This clearly is not the same as:

```Python
'21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700'
```

... which is what you are trying to match.

If you are going to use method `findall`, then extract the first element from the returned list:

```py
    dictionary["time"] = re.findall("[0-9]+\/[A-Z][a-z]*\/[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+ -[0-9]+", line)[0]
```

And do that for every dictionary item. By the way, the above regex as unnecessary escape characters, i.e. `\`. Just use:

```py
    dictionary["time"] = re.findall("[0-9]+/[A-Z][a-z]*/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ -[0-9]+", line)[0]
```

But better would just to use method `search`:

```py
    dictionary["time"] = re.search("[0-9]+/[A-Z][a-z]*/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ -[0-9]+", line).group(0)
```

A simpler regex would be:

```py
    dictionary["time"] = re.search(r'\[([^\]]+)\]', line).group(1)
```

This just matches whatever is between open and closed brackets (`[]`) as capture group 1.

**Update**

I would use a single regular expression with the `match` method to capture all 4 values into capture groups 1 through 4:

```
((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) - -*([a-z]+[0-9]+)* \[([^\]]+)\] "([^"]+)"
```

1. `(` - start of capture group 1.
2. `(?:[0-9]+\.){3}` - matches one or more digits followed by '.' three times (no capture group).
3. `[0-9]+` - matches one or more digits.
4. `)` - end of capture group 1.
5. `-` - matches ' - '.
6. `-*` - matches 0 or more '-'.
7. `([a-z]+[0-9]+)*` - matches name in capture group 2, which may not be present.
8. `\[` - matches ' ['.
9. `([^\]]+)` - matches one or more non-']' characters.
   10.`\] "` - matches '] "'.
10. `([^"]+)` - matches one or more non-'"' characters.
11. `"` - matches '"'.

The code:

```py
import re

line = '46.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622'

def to_dictionary(line):
    dictionary = {}
    m = re.match(r'((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) - [- ]*([a-z]+[0-9]+)* \[([^\]]+)\] "([^"]+)"', line)
    if m:
        dictionary["host"] = m.group(1)
        dictionary["user_name"] = m.group(2)
        dictionary["time"] = m.group(3)
        dictionary["request"] = m.group(4)
    else:
        print('Could not match:', line)
    return dictionary

print(to_dictionary(line))
```

Prints:

```None
{'host': '46.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
```

Comment: Yes, you had that in your regular expression. But I could not assume that you knew exactly what you were doing. I did not see where you explicitly stated in English that the name may be missing and instead a '-' will be present instead. Also, I believe your final regular expression needs to escape with a backslash (or two backslashes if you are not using a raw literal string) the initial `[` character so that it is interpreted just as an open bracket instead of the start of a character class.

Comment: The best way to express that either a '-' or a name will be present (assuming this is indeed the situation) would be with `(?:-|([a-z]+[0-9]+))`. That way you can only have either a single '-' or a single name. The regex you are using accepts '-----booboo123johndoe999'.

Comment: Thanks!! I think i will leave it there as it works but it's useful to know other alternative

Answer (score 0):

Final code

```
    logdatalines = logdata.splitlines()

    logs = []
    for line in logdatalines:
        dictionary = to_dictionary(line)
        logs.append(dictionary)
    return logs


    #return dictionary

def to_dictionary(line):
    dictionary = {}
    m = re.match(r'((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) - ([- ]*[a-z]*[0-9]*) \[([^\]]+)\] "(.*)"', line)
    assert m
    dictionary["host"] = m.group(1)
    dictionary["user_name"] = m.group(2)
    dictionary["time"] = m.group(3)
    dictionary["request"] = m.group(4)
    return dictionary
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).